# How to update File appProperties using Google Drive v3

Tags: python, google-drive-api

With file uploaded and `file_id` known:

```
media_body = MediaFileUpload(filepath, mimetype=mimetype)
body = {'name': os.path.basename(filepath), 'appProperties':{'my_key': 'my_value'}}
file = drive_service.files().create(body=body, media_body=media_body, fields='id, appProperties').execute()
file_id = file['id']
```

How to modify the file's `appProperties` using v3?

There is a [Google Drive API v3 Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143283/google-drive-api-v3-migration) post that could be used to get some idea on things not covered in the documentaion. This post's **Trash / Update** section talks about `update` functionality in Google Drive API v3. 
But it is written in Java and not Python. It suggests of using an empty File object: `File newContent = new File();`

Another post this time for PHP mentions about `update` method and this empty File approach too: [How to update file in google drive v3 PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296311/how-to-update-file-in-google-drive-v3-php)

I would appreciate if someone here would trough a couple of Python snippets to guide me in a right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about following sample? In order to update `appProperties`, you can use drive.files.update. The detail information is [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update).

#### Sample script :

```
body = {'appProperties': {'my_key': 'updated_my_value'}}
updated_file = drive_service.files().update(
    body=body,
    fileId="### file id ###",
    fields='id, appProperties'
).execute()
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: I was using a wrong flag. It must be a `body` flag.

Comment: @Kishan Mehta You can create and update spreadsheet using Sheets API v4. You can see the detail information here https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/