# weird file listing response differences between v2 and v3

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the google-drive-sdk with our company-made device.  We upload pictures made by our device to google drive. After that I try to list the files with a GET request to https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files to get thumbnailLink and webContentLink. Everything is working fine except that when I switch to v3 I don't get the response I should. The documentation says I should get a metadata response like https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files
but I only get: id, kind, name and mimeType. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [Migrate to Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration) documentation, there are changes on how fields were returned.

> Full resources are no longer returned by default. You need to use the `fields` query parameter to request specific fields to be returned. If left unspecified only a subset of commonly used fields are returned.

You can see examples on [Github](https://github.com/googledrive). This SO question might also [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143283/google-drive-api-v3-migration).

Answer (score 0):

In v3 they made all the queries parametric. So you can query passing some parameter like

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                'pageSize': 10,
                'fields': 'files,kind,nextPageToken'
            });
```

This block of code will return you all the information of every file just like v2.

If you are sending a get request then for fetching all the information you can try GET [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](http://GET%20https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)

Suppose you need ownsers and permissions only then set

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                    'pageSize': 10,
                    'fields':'files(owners,permissions),kind,nextPageToken'
                });
```

For GET request  use GET [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files(owners%2Cpermissions)%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files(owners%2Cpermissions)%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)

for reference you can use [Google Developers Documentation for fetching File list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#http-request)