# Migration from Google Drive API from v2 to v3 giving inconsistent results

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a very simple program to list files in a Google Drive. I have written 2 versions, using v2 and v3 of the API. However when I run them I get inconsistent results. v2 works fine, v3 doesn't. They are both written in groovy which is a superset of java. To install groovy use [Sdkman](http://sdkman.io/install.html)

v2.groovy

```
@GrabResolver(name='com.google.apis', root='http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo')
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='com.google.api-client',    module='google-api-client       version='1.12.0-beta'),
    @Grab(group='com.google.apis',      module='google-api-services-drive', version='v2-rev30-1.12.0-beta'),
    @Grab(group='com.google.http-client',   module='google-http-client-jackson',    version='1.12.0-beta')
])

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse

import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory

import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory

import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.*

import groovy.json.*

import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent

class GD {

    def drive
    def credential
    def httpTransport
    def jsonFactory
    def scopes

    def GD (config) {
        httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport ()
        jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory ()
        scopes = DriveScopes.DRIVE

        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(config.accountId)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(config.p12File))
                .setServiceAccountUser (config.accountUser)
                .build();

        credential.refreshToken();

        drive = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(config.applicationName).build()
    }

    def getAllFiles() throws IOException {
        def list = []
        def request = drive.files().list()

        while (true) {
            def files = request.execute()
            list += files.getItems()
            request.pageToken = files.nextPageToken

            if (!request.pageToken)
                break

            if (list.size() % 10 == 0)
                print "${list.size()} ...\r"
        }

        println "${list.size()}"
        return list
    }
}

def config = [
        accountId: '13242342543534653', // replace by your user id
        accountUser: 'xxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com', // replace by your account email
        p12File: '/home/pascal/wep-ffah-f01d3bfec317.p12', // replace by path to your p12File
        applicationName: 'myapp',   // replace by your app
]
def drive = new GD (config)
println "retrieving files"
drive.getAllFiles().each  { println "${it.id} ${it.title}: ${it.mimeType}" }
```

v3.groovy

```
@GrabResolver(name='com.google.apis', root='http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo')
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='com.google.api-client',    module='google-api-client',     version='1.21.0'),
    @Grab(group='com.google.http-client',   module='google-http-client-jackson2',   version='1.21.0'),
    @Grab(group='com.google.apis',      module='google-api-services-drive', version='v3-rev16-1.21.0')
    // @Grab(group='com.google.apis',       module='google-api-services-prediction',version='v1.6-rev59-1.21.0'),

])

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory

// import com.google.api.services.prediction.PredictionScopes
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.*

import groovy.json.*

import java.util.Collections

class GD {
    def drive
    def credential
    def httpTransport
    def jsonFactory
    def scopes

    def GD (config) {
        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
        jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
        scopes = Collections.singleton (DriveScopes.DRIVE)

        credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream (new FileInputStream (config.jsonFile), httpTransport, jsonFactory)
        credential.serviceAccountScopes = scopes
        drive = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(config.applicationName).build()
    }

    def getAllFiles() throws IOException {
        def list = []
        def request = drive.files().list()

        while (true) {
            def files = request.execute()
            list += files.getFiles()
            request.pageToken = files.getNextPageToken()

            if (!request.pageToken && request.pageToken.length > 0)
                break

            if (list.size() % 10 == 0)
                print "${list.size()} ...\r"

        }

        println "${list.size()}"
        return list
    }
}

/************************************** Start here ******************************************/

def config = [
    jsonFile: '/home/myhome/yourapp-b954bxxxxx.json', // repalce by your json credential file
    applicationName: 'yourapp', // set your app
]

def drive = new GD (config)
println "retrieving files"
drive.getAllFiles ().each  { println "${it.id} ${it.name}: ${it.mimeType}" }
```

Comment: This [document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143283/google-drive-api-v3-migration?rq=1) posted by IvaRF may answer the problem you are encountering. I hope this help

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Thank you. after further investigation, I am deciding to stay with v2 for now until the api is a little more mature. Thank you for your time