# Getting File Metadata from Google API V3 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I am trying to retrieve file metadata from Google drive API V3 in Python. I did it in API V2, but failed in V3.
I tried to get metadata by this line:

```
data = DRIVE.files().get(fileId=file['id']).execute()
```

but all I got was a dict of `'id'`, `'kind'`, `'name'`, and `'mimeType'`. How can I get `'md5Checksum'`, `'fileSize'`, and so on?

I read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#get).
I  am supposed to get all the metadata by `get()` methods, but all I got was a small part of it.

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os

from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('storage.json', scope=SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
DRIVE = build('drive','v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

files = DRIVE.files().list().execute().get('files',[])

for file in files:
    print('\n',file['name'],file['id'])
    data = DRIVE.files().get(fileId=file['id']).execute()
    print('\n',data)

print('Done')
```

I tried this answer:
[Google Drive API v3 Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143283/google-drive-api-v3-migration)

> ### List
>
> Files returned by `service.files().list()` do not contain information now, i.e. every field is null. If you want list on v3 to behave like in v2, call it like this:
>
> > ```
> > service.files().list().setFields("nextPageToken, files");
> > ```

but I get a Traceback:

```
DRIVE.files().list().setFields("nextPageToken, files")
AttributeError: 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute 'setFields'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose you want to get the md5 hash of a file given its `fileId`, you can do it like this:

```
DRIVE = build('drive','v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
file_service = DRIVE.files()
remote_file_hash = file_service.get(fileId=fileId, fields="md5Checksum").execute()['md5Checksum']
```

To list some files on the Drive:

```
results = file_service.list(pageSize=10, fields="files(id, name)").execute()
```

I have built a small application [gDrive-auto-sync](https://github.com/Anmol-Singh-Jaggi/gDrive-auto-sync) containing more examples of API usage.
It's well-documented, so you can have a look at it if you want.
[Here](https://github.com/Anmol-Singh-Jaggi/gDrive-auto-sync/blob/master/gDrive-auto-sync/upload.py) is the main file containing all the code. It might look like a lot but more than half of lines are just comments.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to retrieve all the fields for a file resource, simply set `fields='*'`

In your above example, you would run

```
data = DRIVE.files().get(fileId=file['id'], fields='*').execute()
```

This should return all the available resources for the file as listed in:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files

Comment: This is great — how can I set a field?  For instance, I'd like to run something like DRIVE.files().set(fileId=file['id'], fields={'writersCanShare': False}) but there's no set() method.  I don't see a post() method either.  Thoughts?

Comment: You can set a field using the `update` method. Check out this link https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update

Answer (score 0):

There is a library PyDrive that provide easy interactions with google drive

https://googledrive.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/filelist.html

Their example:

```
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth) # Create GoogleDrive instance with authenticated GoogleAuth instance

# Auto-iterate through all files in the root folder.
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:
  print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))
```

All you need is `file1['your key']`