# Google Drive Rest API v3 - how to move a file to the trash?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

The Google Drive Rest API v3 has a Drive.Files.Delete method, but that permanently deletes the file.How do i move the file to the trash?

I looked at the docs for updating file metadata, and i tried to do this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
File file = new File();
file.setTrashed(true);
driveService.files().update(f.getId(), file).execute();
```

Comment: I was using service account to delete file, and then looking trash of admin user)))) of course it wasn't there, because file was going to service account's trash

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see any error with your code on how to move a file to [trash](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#methods) wherein you'll use `files.update` with `{'trashed':true}`.

Sample code in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35143284/5832311):

> The solution is to create an empty File setting only the new values:
>
> ```
> File newContent = new File();
> newContent.setTrashed(true);
> service.files().update(fileId, newContent).execute();
> ```

I have tried this in Google Drive [Try it!](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update#try-it) and successfully moved the file to trash.

Just make sure that the `File` refers to `com.google.api.services.drive.model.File` and it is **not** `java.io.File`.