# Google Drive API v3 getting root folder Id in java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I tried several things bu couldn't get the root folder id in Java Api v3.

What I tried:

```
String id = service.files().get("fileId=root").setFields("id").execute().getId();

String id = service.files().get("fileId=root").setFields("?fields=id").execute().getId();

String id = service.files().get("root").setFields("?fields=id").execute().getId();

String id = service.files().get("fileId=root and ?fields=id").execute().getId();
```

I am getting this errors:

```
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "fields",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Invalid field selection ?fields=id",
    "reason" : "invalidParameter"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid field selection ?fields=id"
}

An error occurred: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "fileId",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "File not found: .",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "File not found: ."
}
```

I looked the [migration](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#fields) document and other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143283/google-drive-api-v3-migration) but still couldn't get the root id. Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, why you require the root id?

Comment: I am doing a migration from API v2 to v3. The previous code uses this id in several calls so I am trying to get the id.

Comment: If this could help, In the Try API [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get), I just did `files.get` for a file in the root and passed `parents` as field option and I got the `ID`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I will try it. However, in the migration document it says "for rootFolderId do files.get with fileId=root and ?fields=id". Do you know how can I get this work?

Comment: Yes, just tried with what you suggested. file.get("root").setFields("id") may be a good try.

Comment: It is working now. It was the only combination that I haven't tried :) Thank you!

Comment: I will add that as an answer and please accept if I have helped you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following combination to see if that works.

```
String id = service.files().get("root").setFields("id").execute().getId();
```

Comment: Actually, in most cases, no need to get the root id. You can use the alias root to refer to the root folder anywhere a file ID is provided

Comment: @skyfree the reason you would need the actual root id is where you get the files metadata and you want to check if it's parent is the root. The 'parents' property will contain the actual root id and not the string 'root'.

Answer (score 1):

To execute the above combination, you have to give your application full access to use Drive.
OAuth 2.0 scope that needs to be given: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly