# Google DRIVE API V3 - Get a folder id with name

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I could find only ways to get the root folder id from google drive api -[REFERENCE]: [Google Drive API v3 getting root folder Id in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483808/google-drive-api-v3-getting-root-folder-id-in-java) . I have to get the folder id by giving a name. Is there anyway i could get Folder id of a directory in Drive by passing its name.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for a specific folder with these parameters:

```
name = 'your-folder-name'
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
```

The mime type makes sure, that you are only searching for folders. For more information, take a look at the documentation of the search parameters [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).

Comment: @GaneshR Can you give me the example how to execute this code?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to find the folder id with folder name. if such folder is not found it will result folderId as 0.

```
let folderName = "myFolder";
let result = await drive.files.list({
    q: "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false",
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    spaces: 'drive',
}).catch(e => console.log("eeee", e));
let folder = result.data.files.filter(x => x.name === folderName);
var folderId = folder.length?folder[0].id:0;
console.log(folder.id)
```

Comment: You are a life saver @Selver Mary. Exactly what I was looking. I will give 1000 upvotes if I could. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

// $client will be get auth detail

$server = new Google_Service_Drive ( $client );

```
            $metaDataArray= array(
                q=>"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='folder_name' and trashed=false",
               spaces =>'drive',
               fields =>'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
           );

           $fl = $server->files->listFiles( $metaDataArray);
```

This is in php . you can just convert to java