# Google Drive API - How to get folder id by folder name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-drive-api

I am trying to get folder id by folder name by using google drive api.
Is there anyway i could get Folder id of a folder in drive by passing its name. I am developing this in .net using c#.

I have tried the code provided on the below link
[Google DRIVE API V3 - Get a folder id with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757635/google-drive-api-v3-get-a-folder-id-with-name)

But it was not clearly understood how to execute that.

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: @MindSwipe Agree, But after that which method to execute that's not clear

Comment: Check out [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters) from google itself with sample code for .NET

Comment: @MindSwipe Yeah but how to pass the metadata in that case

Comment: Which metadata?

Comment: name and mimetype which we pass in metadata, like shown in the example

Comment: Instead of `request.Q = "mimeType='image/jpeg'` replace it with `request.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"` and (I'm not sure from here on out) add the name field to the `Fields` Property like so: `request.Fields = "nextPageToken, **name=your-name-here**, files(id, name)";`, you can always use string interpolation ($"") to set your name to whatever

Comment: Yeah.. I have already tried till this point. But it give error as invalid field selection for name field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@XamDev
Let's say I have a folder "test" on my google drive. I would like to find this folder by giving Google drive API, the name of the folder and restrict the results only to folders. This is how you can do it (It's working in my case):

```
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 10;
        listRequest.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name = 'test'";
        listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
        .Files;
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {   //My TextBlock(WPF)
                ListedFiles.Text = $"{file.Name}, {file.Id} \n"; 
            }
        }
```

The part of the source code comes from: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet and the parameters that you can search for: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters