# google drive fetch users installed apps in version v3

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apps

I am migrating google drive v2 to version v3.Even thought Google wrote this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration), there are many gaps in it.

Also there is doc for same migration at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143283/google-drive-api-v3-migration),but this is not helping in my case.

In version v2 I was getting users [installed apps](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/apps/list) like this-

```
AppList apps = service.apps().list().execute();
apps.getItems();
```

How can I get users installed apps in version v3.Suggestions would be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

A number of methods are not available in v3  If you check 
[Migrate to Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration)

You will notice there is no new method for these calls

> apps.get   n/a 
>   apps.list   n/a

Answer: There is no method for getting a list of users installed application in google Drive v3

Comment: Is there any alternative for it?Why google stoped such feature?How can alreaddy running apps will suport these feature in case of migration.Is there any work around for the same,anyhow.

Comment: I know of no alternative.   I cant tell you why Google would do something sorry.   When they deprecate v2 you will probably have a year before your application stops working.    My advice would be to post it as a feature request asking them to consider adding the method to the new API https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%2B