# How to untrash a Google Drive file with PHP Google API client?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/untrash) says:

```
/*
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 */
$service->files->untrash($fileId);
```

But there is no such method in the library, if I call this I get:

```
[Error]                                                                  
  Call to undefined method Google\Service\Drive\Resource\Files::untrash()
```

My client library version is:

```
"google/apiclient": "^2.12.1",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client library version `2.12.1` uses Google Drive API v3, this new version doesn't have an `untrashed()` method but you can use [update()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) instead, try this:

```
$FileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(
    array(
        'trashed' => false
    )
);

$service->files->update($fileId,$FileMetadata);
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143283/google-drive-api-v3-migration/35143284#35143284) with additional examples of the differences between v2 and v3. You can also find more samples for this new version [here](https://github.com/googleworkspace/php-samples/tree/main/drive/snippets/drive_v3/src).